# Relaciones en Laravel8 Return value of App\Models\Turnos::personas() must be an instance of App\Models\BelongsTo

Tags: laravel

estoy intentando hacer una api rest que se conecte a una base de datos y devuelva información en un json, en la base de datos hay dos tablas "personas" y "turnos", la idea es que se puedan consultar los turnos y los datos de la persona que tomo ese turno.
La parte de consultar todos los turnos está funcionando bien.

```
public function index(){
    $turnos = Turnos::all();

    return response() ->json([
        'code'=> 200,
        'status'=> 'success',
        'message'=> $turnos
    ],200);
}
```

Ahora cuando quiero consular un turno en particular y los datos de la persona me da error.

```
public function show($id){
    $turnos = Turnos::find($id)->personas();

    return response() ->json([
        'code'=> 200,
        'status'=> 'success',
        'message'=> $turnos
    ],200);
}
```

TypeError
Return value of App\Models\Turnos::personas() must be an instance of App\Models\BelongsTo, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo returned

Modelo Personas

```
class Personas extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'personas';

    public function turnos(): HasMany
    {
    return $this->hasMany(Turnos::class);
    }

}
```

Modelo Turnos

```
class Turnos extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'turnos';

    public function personas(): BelongsTo
    {
    return $this->belongsTo(Personas::class);
    }

}
```

No cree foreing Key pero leí la documentación de laravel y nombre los campos para que Eloquent estableciera correctamente las relaciones, es decir las dos tablas tienen una columna "id" como primary key y en "turnos" una columna "indexada" como persona_id.

No sé en donde me estoy equivocando.
Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.
Saludos.
Guillermo

Comment: Haz algun debug y fijate que eloquent no esté tomando personas_id en vez de persona_id como fk convencional. Tipicamente el nombre del modelo es un sustantivo en singular, pero ahí estan en plural, y eso puede confundir a eloquent

Comment: O esa clase `BelongsTo` en `public function personas(): BelongsTo` podríaser que no la estés importando correctamente de `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, agregue la linea use Illuminate\...\BelongsTo en el modelo de turnos y dejo de dar error, no trae nada, pero no da error, es un avance muy grande, también puse los nombres de los modelos en singular, pero sigue sin traer nada. Voy a seguir investigando antes de volver a molestar con otra pregunta.